# ImportError: cannot import name 'NUMPY' in openpyxl.compat.numbers

Tags: python, jupyter, openpyxl

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsg3y.png)

Hello! I'm trying to work with Excel files on Jupyter notebook. But I haven't succeed because of problem with openpyxl (openpyxl installed). If anyone know how to solve this problem, please help.

Comment: Should be lowercase `numpy`

Comment: NUMPY and PANDAS are flags for openpyxl to know whether the libraries are installed. Looks like you have a broken installation.

Answer (score 1):

It should be lowercase `numpy`, python is case sensitive.